# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

i have created the folloiwng view model class

```
public class viewmodelclass
{
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

then i wrote the following method to create viewmodelclassobjects in my repository model class:-

```
public IQueryable<viewmodelclass> d (int number)
    { var q_t =  new viewmodelclass()
    {
            Message = "This question current;y have" + number,
            Total = number,
            Questions = from question123 in entities1.Questions
                               where question123.QuestionID >= number
                               select question123
        };
 return q_t;}
```

which will be called using the following method inside my controller class:-

```
 public ActionResult dd (int number = 0)
    { var q2 = elearningrepository.d(number);
        return View(q2);}
```

but i am receiving the following error on ***return q_t***:-
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
so how i can overcome this error ?
BR

Comment: but i am creating multiple viewmodelclass to be passed to the view

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple viewmodels for a view. The idea is that a single viewmodel wraps up all the content you're going to need there. Sounds like you need to refactor your view model to contain the collection, rather than creating a view model for each item of it.

Comment: thanks for ur reply; my view use for "@foreach (var item in Model)" so i can not loop through the object in my viewmodelclass unlesss i use IEnumerable<Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass> at the view level, so i should use Iqueryable on the controller and model level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the "d" method to return just the viewmodelclass

```
public viewmodelclass d (int number)
    { var q_t =  new viewmodelclass()
    {
            Message = "This question current;y have" + number,
            Total = number,
            Questions = from question123 in entities1.Questions
                               where question123.QuestionID >= number
                               select question123
        };
 return q_t;}
```

Modify your view to expect a viewmodelclass as its model.
you really don't have to pass an IQueryable in this instance.

Comment: i think i should retrun it as IQueryable as the view will recive muliple objects of viewmodelclass.anyway i change as u mentioned in ur code but i am receiving the following error on the view "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass]'".

Comment: @john G You need modify the view .. could you post the first 3 lines of the view in your post.. just edit your post and add the first 3 lines of the view

Comment: @model IEnumerable<Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "dd";
}

<h2>dd</h2>

Comment: @john G first line should be @ model Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass

Answer (score 2):

Erm - at the risk of sounding obvious it's the wrong return type. Use

```
 public viewmodelclass d (int number)
        { var q_t =  new viewmodelclass()
        {
                Message = "This question current;y have" + number,
                Total = number,
                Questions = from question123 in entities1.Questions
                                   where question123.QuestionID >= number
                                   select question123
            };
     return q_t;}
```

Comment: i think i should retrun it as IQueryable as the view will recive muliple objects of viewmodelclass.anyway i change as u mentioned in ur code but i am receiving the following error on the view "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass]'"

Comment: @johnG. OK but here you are only creating one object. Does it need to be IQueryable. I suspect IEnumerable would work - in that case - create your single object and wrap it in a generic list of type LIst<viewmodelclass>. You return type can then be IEnumerable<viewmodelclass>. IList interface implements IEnumerable. IQueryable can convert to IEnumerable (it has the ToList function to do it). Hope that's of some use

Comment: @johnG You're getting this error because your view is expecting your model to be of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass].  `IEnumerable`, like other collections, can hold multiple instances of the same type (in this case `viewmodelclass`) so you would use it to pass multiple instances of `viewmodelclass` to your view contained within the `IEnumerable`.  If you just want to pass a single instance of `viewmodelclass` to your view, you need to change the @model directive in the view to be: `@model Esystem.ViewModels.viewmodelclass`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating a single instance of your viewmodelclass class and trying to return it as an IQueryable. Simple fix, change your return type on the "d" method on your repository from `IQueryable<viewmodelclass>` to `viewmodelclass`.